# What is the scriptCode in a P2WSH transaction?

Tags: script, segregated-witness, p2wsh

Let's say I am spending from a 2-of-2 multisig with this script:

```
522103c2f21de0f430251d8e3987fbe89ff51f3d6f3a48b234b84b60ddb9f24d587cf52103e0948a03f50377290847d27c93d383b8ab7e2d0bc065e96e0e1136b315388b5452ae

OP_2 <len(pubkey1)> <pubkey1> <len(pubkey2)> <pubkey2> OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

What would go in the scriptCode according to BIP143? Is it just the script listed above? Here is the relevant part from [BIP143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki).

> For P2WSH witness program,
>   - if the witnessScript does not contain any OP_CODESEPARATOR, the scriptCode is the witnessScript serialized as scripts inside CTxOut.
>   - if the witnessScript contains any OP_CODESEPARATOR, the scriptCode is the witnessScript but removing everything up to and including the last executed OP_CODESEPARATOR before the signature checking opcode being executed, serialized as scripts inside CTxOut. (The exact semantics is demonstrated in the examples below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the scriptCode would be that multisig script.

Comment: Thanks.

Now that I just found out, I wanted to add that in the bip143 transaction digest, the scriptCode needs to be preceded by a byte indicating the length of the scriptCode.